# How to query checking if a month is between two dates?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm looking for query in postgresql to check whether a month is between two dates or not.

I know how to check if a date is between two date or not. Postgres also have a function to do that.

Let's say I have a a_table with rows:

```
ID | start_date (timestamp)  | end_date (timestamp)
1  | 2019-07-20 00:00        | 2020-03-20 00:00
2  | 2019-08-20 00:00        | 2020-08-30 00:00
```

I have a to return the row that include a month between the start_date and end_date.
Let's say i have a month 2019-08.
So when i count

```
Select count(*) from a_table 
Where [some where clause]
```

it returns 2 rows, ID 1 and ID 2

AND when i have a month 2020-01 it only return ID 1

Comment: What if the input is `2020-01` and you have a row with `start_date = 2020-01-05` and `end_date 2020-01-15`? Should that be included as well?

Comment: Why isn't the second row included for 2020-01?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [date  range](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) for this.

It's not clear to me what should happen if the start/end date in the table only covers part of a month.

If you only want to consider the full month, use the "contains" operator

```
select count(*)
from the_table
where daterange(start_date::date, end_date::date, '[]') @> daterange('2019-08-01'::date, '2019-09-01'::date, '[)');
```

The `<@` is the "is contained" operator which tests if the left range (the values from the table) is contained in the right hand range (the month you want to test). The comparison is done with an "open interval", which means `'2019-09-01'` is *excluded* from it. The above would not consider rows that do not contain the full August.

If you want to include partial matches as well, use the "overlaps" operator `&&` instead:

```
select count(*)
from the_table
where daterange(start_date::date, end_date::date, '[]') && daterange('2019-08-01'::date, '2019-09-01'::date, '[)');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use to_date() in your where clause. So that your where clause would be like this.

```
WHERE '2019-08' BETWEEN to_date(start_date, 'YYYY-MM') and to_date(end_date ,'YYYY-MM')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend writing this as:

```
WHERE end_date >= TO_DATE('2019-08', 'YYYY-MM') AND
      start_date < TO_DATE('2019-08', 'YYYY-MM') + INTERVAL '1 MONTH'
```

That is, the period includes at least one day of the month, because it starts before the end of the month and ends after the start of the month.

In addition, this has no functions on the columns in the table.  So, if an index is available on either column, then it can be used.  If you define the start/end as a range, then that provides other opportunities for using indexes.